# Do scenes get restarted when changing orientation on mobile devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-orientation

I develop a mobile app on Unity, and I decided to let the user flip the orientation whenever they want (landscape/portrait). But as I remember- when you flip the device on Android- the Activity gets restarted so you need to store the variables and restore after the change. But since I develop everything in Unity- I'm not sure about the steps I have to make in order to allow orientation changes.  Do I have to store the variables? What happens after the user rotates their device? What information might I lose besides the objects positions?  Also is there any recommended tool for making 3d game objects fit the screen? like the "anchor presets" option that UI elements have?

Comment: *"What happens after the user rotates their device?"* Try it. Build a simple app with Unity then try it on any Android device. You will save yourself time and others time. All of your questions are just something you could try on your side. If you try and still find things confusing then ask.

Comment: _"All of your questions are just something you could try on your side."_  Be sure that I write questions here only after I checked and researched! Because I might try and see that everything works fine and find problems later on. When programming you should always assume that you are missing something- and this is why I'm asking the experts. And since I couldn't see any similar question here- I submitted mine.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it is better to try it then post the outcome and ask if the outcome is expected otherwise someone will have to do that for you.

Comment: It's not about a test or a bug, it's a general question about Unity. Yes or no.  If you would have asked me the same question but in a different language like Android which I know better- I would answer "you should store variables because the activity is restarted" and attach some information about it. There is nothing to debug here- it's a question for experts about how Unity works, but I'll find the answer.